# How to integrate React Native to existing iOS project

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Very excited to see Facebook open source React Native on F8 2015. Although they provide `react-native-cli` to generate an empty React Native project, I still don't know how to integrate React Native to my current project which uses Xcode workspace and CocoaPods.

Comment: None of the answers mentioned below are valid anymore. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A full step by step guide on how to get started with React Native in an existing project is here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the link to official docs. However you missed one character 'd' in the URL. Should be http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app.html#content.

Comment: thanks, no idea how I managed to do that ;) I have corrected the answer

Comment: none of these projects are active anywhere. Why is it so painful to do this? I have been struggling from days

Answer (score 5):

You can checkout this demo:
https://github.com/dsibiski/react-native-hybrid-app-examples

Before you start to use the react native, you should read their document flowing:
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

[image]
then we should run `npm install -g react-native-cli` to install command line tool.

The next step is to install the cocoapods.
[image]

Then get into your Xcode project directory, create `package.json` file.The content is like this:

[image]

Then you run `npm install` in terminal.After a moment you will find a directory `node_modules`
The next step is to run `pod init` .The `Podfile` will be created. So just open and configure it just like flowing

[image]

Then your Podfile will just like this [image]

> You should pay attention to the React path you have configured in Podfile.

Then run `pod install`. You'll get the workspace.

Also you need a server or offline bundle , checkout this

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/240

Some problem you may have after that:

1.Naming collision detected:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3440

2.Not available on ios(App Extension).....

Add code in Podfile

`post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['APPLICATION_EXTENSION_API_ONLY'] = 'NO'
      end
   end
end`

Hope it's helpful : )

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps. I wonder if you can help - I keep getting "framework not found React". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792596/ld-framework-not-found-react

Answer (score 4):

React Native is available as a CocoaPod and distributed as part of React Native (inside `node_modules` installed via npm).

To integrate with an existing app is very easy, you just add an instance of `RCTRootView` wherever you like in your view hierarchy, and your React Native application will run inside it. See [this guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html).