# How to integrate `React Native SDK` provided by Facebook in our application?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, react-native, ios10

I want to integrate `React Native SDK` in my app. I have followed guidance provided on site. But when I run my app it gives error like :

[image: Build failed reason]

And also I have check that frameworks is added or not then frameworks are added but they are displayed like :

[image: Framework included, but not showing as normal]

What is going wrong ? I tried same as giving in tutorial, but when execute command on my `Terminal`, it stop working at this point.

[image: Terminal log status]

I have referred these guideline :

1. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-ios
3. [How to integrate React Native to existing iOS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307731/how-to-integrate-react-native-to-existing-ios-project)

If anyone has solution, please share with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Place Facebook SDK in your documents folder and then open your project  in Xcode. Click your project in the left menu and select the build settings tab, give 'framework path' the path to your FBSDK in documents.
2. Make sure your folder name is FacebookSDK.
3. Add the Facebook framework in Embedded Binaries.

Answer (score 1):

https://tylermcginnis.com/installing-the-facebook-sdk-into-a-react-native-android-and-ios-app/

This works like charm on android as well as ios.

Hope this helps.